# Visual stuio web deploy package

Tags: visual-studio, web-deployment

I am using vs 2015 update 3. In order to deploy my website, I create a web deploy package from the publish menu.
When I deploy that package, sometimes, some of the dll's are corrupted. When I ran the app I get an error that the dll is missing. When I open the dll with a disassembler, it is marked as an unmanged dll.
I can't find any difference between projects that work finק and the one's that don't, or between the dll that is fine and the one that is not.
I also tried deploying from VS Straight to my local IIS but that didn't help either.
What could this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of debugging I found the problem.
In order to change variables in different environments we use parameters.xml file to set up the variables. There we had a settings to run on all js files and replace url's. The dll that was getting corrupted was newtonsoft.json.dll. since there is ".js" in the file name, the dll was beeing manipulated as well.
The solution was in the parameters.xml file to change the setting to be .js$. In that case it look for files that end with .js only and not all files.